# How to add an array of objects to a JFrame or a JPanel in Netbeans?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am developing an ant simulator for my final year project.  Here is a design of my work:

[image]

The problem is since I can't find a way to add an array of objects into a JFrame or a JPanel, or arrange objects into an array.  Source code are protected by Netbeans so I can't even modify it manually.  Is there any way to add arrays of objects, or is there any other way to do the grid world?

Comment: Can you show what the current GUI looks like? What objects are you trying to add to the frame/panel and how?

Comment: there are only controllers (Play/Pause, Stop, update rate slider) in my current GUI.  About 500x500 pixels is reserved for the grid world.  I guess I will be using JPanels to represents grids of the world.

Comment: You mean that you want a `JPanel` for each square? I would think that a `JLabel` would do better there. The panel is certainly the way to do for the while "container" grid though.

Comment: Do you have to do it this way? It's quite expensive rather than just painting it all on a single panel.

Comment: @WalterM If that is directed to me then the answer is it depends on the functionality of the GUI. I don't know what interactions need to happen, how it updates real-time and what calculations are involved, and how many of these grids are there simultaneously and what their sizes are.

Comment: i dont think `JLabel` is a good idea, since i might need much more than just text label to represent each grid.  painting is much better but i am not so sure if it is suitable for a grid world simulator.

Comment: *"Source code are protected by Netbeans so I can't even modify it manually."*  you should either learn to use the IDE, or stop using it.  At the moment, it has made you its bitch..

Comment: @AndrewThompson well I guess I can still edit those protected parts, it is just not safe to do in that way.  usually it is something to stop me from screwing things up so I tend to stick with it.  but of course, I can always manually edit those parts with some other IDE or even a notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). With `GridBagConstraints` you can control the placement of `JComponent`s.

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
cons.gridx = 2;
cons.gridy = 2;

pane.add(theComponent, cons);
```

It is also possible to use the `GridBagLayout` in [Netbeans UI editor](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/customizer/).

Comment: Since every component in the grid is the same size, a GridLayout is probably a better choice.